# Prevent Powershell file write splitting/wrapping text in to multiple lines, when run from Azure Automation

Tags: powershell, text-manipulation

I have executed the following commands from Azure Automation(to run inside a VM). I tried all file write commands(Out-File, Add-Content, Set-Content) but the output string always comes in multiple lines.

```
$stringScript = "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://dsdsdssd.blob.core.windows.net/sdsdsd-dfdf-installs-8/sdsd/git.inf?sp=r&st=2021-06-06T10:23:50Z&se=2023-10-01T18:23:50Z&spr=https&sv=2020-02-10&sr=b&sig=sdsdsG8i0asdsdsdsdsdeee%3D' -OutFile git.inf -UseBasicParsing;"
```

- $stringScript  | Out-File -FilePath $installationFilePath -Append -Force -NoNewline
  -width 400
- Set-Content -Path $installationFilePath -Value $stringScript

This the output I get(always cut into 3 lines/wrapped)
[image]

The output I want is single line
[image]

When these same commands are run inside the VM it outputs single line. From Azure automation it is not. How to achieve this? My end goal is to execute this text as a powershell script inside the VM.

Comment: Looks like "Word Wrap" is toggled in notepad. `Format -> Word Wrap` in the top menu

Comment: not that. I checked. I opened this in powershell editor too.

Comment: this is run from Azure automation. I will edit the question. in a normal powershell this does not happen .

Comment: how are you running azure automation then? It looks more like an issue with how this command gets input/saved than the actual `Out-File` commands. Are you pasting into a browser somewhere? You can test or get around it by doing something like `$a='[first 100 chars]'` `$b='[next 100 chars]'` `$c=[etc]` and then `$stringScript=($a,$,b,$c -join '')`

Comment: Azure automation .PS1 can run a func inside the VM

Comment: If not what @MathiasR.Jessen said, then you could normalize the string `($stringScript -replace '\s+', ' ').Trim()` yourself and see if that makes the difference

Comment: Are you saying to bring the textlines back to single line? Then there will be multiple line of texts that will be sent to this text file. They should all form their own line.